# Attempting simple javascript read/print operation against my parse.com database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm confused on how to get the javascript to run.

I have a base installation of a parse project on my mac and I have deployed it over and over to my custom *parse.com provided* sitename.parse.com without error.

I ran "parse new gwhizcloud" which created a simple directory structure. I replaced the index.html with the following content, then ran "parse deploy".  So far so good.  But when I hit my web site all I get is "User Emails" printed to the web page.

Here are my directory contents that I am publishing

cloud/main.js 
config/global.json 
public/index.html

All the files are pristine except for index.html which is listed out below

What am I missing? 
Also, where do I look to find the console.log output?
Even my "alert" calls below do not seem to fire.

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.13.min.js"></script>
<script>
var GWUserObject;

$(document).ready(function() {

    Parse.initialize("1U8vTfgwwNSGr<private>y4pawka6x", "Xv3zic5bRl<private>BwhYFqpcpda");
    GWUserObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    console.log( "i feel ready to score!" );
    var query = new Parse.Query(GWUserObject);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " of them.");
        var s = '';
        for(var i=0, len<results.length; i++) {
            var result = results[i];  
            alert(object.id + ' - ' + result.get('email'));
            s+= '<p>';
            s+= '<b>id:</b> '+ result.objectId + '::';
            s+= '<b>Username:</b> '+ result.attributes.username + '::';
            s+= 'Email verified: ' + result.attributes.emailVerified + '::';
            s+= 'Email: ' + result.attributes.email + '<br/>';
            s+= '</p>'
        }

        $("#list").html(s);

    },
        error: function(error) 
        {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

});

</script>
<style>
body {
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
font-family: arial;
}
input {
width: 100%;
height: 25px;
}
textarea {
width: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2>User Emails</h2>

<div id="list">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved::   Had a syntax error in this line:             for(var i=0, len